# Azure SQL Database Copy Command Causes Slowness In Source Azure App

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell

We are using Devops to recreate our demo environment. Within the Devops deployment we have an Azure Powershell task to copy our production Azure SQL database to a "demo" database on the same server the prod db is located on.

We first search for the databases on the server and if the "demo" database exists we delete it:

```
Remove-AzSqlDatabase  -ResourceGroupName prdResource -ServerName  prdServer -DatabaseName demoDb
```

Then we copy the prod db to the demo db:

```
New-AzSqlDatabaseCopy  -ResourceGroupName prdResource -ServerName prdServer -DatabaseName prodDb -CopyDatabaseName demoDb
```

Finally we set the service level on the demoDb:

```
Set-AzSqlDatabase      -ResourceGroupName prdResource -ServerName prdServer -DatabaseName demoDb -Edition "Standard" -RequestedServiceObjectiveName "S4"
```

This all works fine and the demo db is created correctly with the appropriate service level. The issue is our Azure prod webapp that is connected to the prod database struggles with performance issues. Calls that used to take ~2 seconds just prior to the copy db, now take 30+ seconds. We found if we restart the webApp that clears the issue.

Just wondering why the copy db command is effecting our performance on the web app? Are there other settings we should be using with the copy command? We have ran this process several times and get the same performance issues each time we run.

From our understanding this process should not have any negative side effects on the prod db, is that a correct assumption? Any other ways of fixing the issue without having to restart the webApp?

Comment: Have you looked at the DTU usage in the portal for the production database. I assume this spikes when the copy occurs? If you leave the system alone for (say) 30 mins does the DTU usage drop down or does it really require that restart?

Comment: The DTU does spike but not bad. The copy process runs at 1:00am on Sat. We are trying the webApp at 8:00am Saturday, well after the copy process finished and DTU leveled off. It seems the connection in the webApp is not stable or something as then the restart clears everything out again and everything works as expected.

Comment: You can try some other ways to copy an azure database as describe [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-copy). You can also submit this issue [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues?q="baf2eb27-05bf-8d85-2a34-2f6c0ef739b1"+is%3Aopen) to let the developer know about this issue.

Comment: I have posted other Azure related issues here and the Azure folks answered them. Are they no longer monitoring StackOverflow posts for Azure issues?

Answer (score 0):

Scale out your sql database tier and located webapp and db to be in the same region.

These two changes resulted in a massive performance increase.

Also, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-intelligent-insights-troubleshoot-performance) to troubleshoot Azure SQL Database performance issues with Intelligent Insights.

Answer (score 0):

The DTU's really don't seem to be the issue as they don't go above 20%. We have a DevOps deployment in place that runs all the tasks and that is scheduled each Sat at 1:00am. Here is a screenshot of the DTUs for that database during that timeframe:

[image: Prod DB DTU]

Also the DB and the WebApp are both in the East US Region so that also should not be the issue.

Again, restarting the webapp clears up the issue so that points to it not being a DB/DTU issue.